# $f_n\rightarrow f$ in every $L^p(\mathbb R^d)$

Tags: lp-spaces

Is this correct? If $f\in L^1(\mathbb R^d)\cap L^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ then there exists $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $C^\infty(\mathbb R^d)\cap L^1(\mathbb R^d)\cap L^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L^p(\mathbb R^d) $ for every $p\in [1,\infty)$.
I don't how to prove or disprove this. Maybe using the theorem of Riesz-Fischer?

Comment: You only need to prove that $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$ and $(f_n)$ is bounded in $L^\infty$.

Comment: Why do I only have to prove $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L^1$ and that $f_n$ is bounded in $L^\infty$? @daw

Comment: as this implies the claim by Hoelder inequality.